# Conversation scoped and jsf redirect

Tags: java, jsf, paypal, seam, cdi

is it possible to maintaining conversation during redirect to external url?
I started paypal transaction with CDI conversation bean and next there is faces redirect to paypal page when I log in and doing payment and next paypal returning to my page and I want to have the same instance of my backing bean to remember details which I sent to paypal.

When paypal redirects back to my page, he appends to url transaction token and payer ID but I don't have any information about quantity of products which user bought. So I want to remember the quantity from before redirect. Now, after paypal returns to my site I call method doExpressCheckout and I want to pass quantity and other transaction details because I can set entirely different details than before the transaction and there is possible strange situation when customer accept on paypal page that buying some products for 10$, but I set 100$ after paypal redirects again to my page and customer will have no idea how much he paid.
I don't know why that this happens.

I use SOAP api.

Comment: Looks like you should change from Conversation scoped to Session scoped.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, I'm not sure how it works, but it feels like paypal may not be obliged to return the process with the JSESSION_ID. Would the browser automatically re-add it on a redirect from an external site?

Comment: @kolossus why would you need the JSESSION_ID as part of the request query string if you save the session in server?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza how would the server identify the returning request from paypal and match it with a saved session, if the JSESSION_ID is not present in the returning request from paypal?

Comment: @kolossus if the client browser is still open the session won't die even if you leave the site and come back later (of course, assuming user is still within the session timeout). By the way, the JSESSION_ID can be stored in a cookie (or use another mechanism).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I'd have thought that paypal might need to encode the JSESSION_ID into the return URL, fearing that the browser might not include it on a redirect from paypal(if it were a fresh request from the browser, then I'm confident that the JSESSION_ID identifier would be supplied). No matter, if you're sure, you're sure :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can resume your conversation from an external redirect. Just include the `cid=nnn` in the return URL you pass to PayPal. For example:

```
returnUrl = "http://myip/myapp/return.seam?cid=" + Conversation.instance().getId();
details.setReturnURL(returnUrl);
...
```

As the 2 minute default for conversation timeout is rather limited, you will eventually want to increase the conversation timeout before placing the call to PayPal:

```
Conversation.instance().setTimeout(900000); // 15 minutes
```

However, doing this is not necessarily a good idea as it keeps data around for potentially a long time, and you need to keep the session cookie as well for this scheme to work (so you must increase the session timeout as well if necessary).

A better strategy would be to keep the transaction data persistently (db or disk), associate a randomly generated ID to the data and retrieve it on return from PayPal. This way you don't need to keep the conversation in memory.

Answer (score 0):

> When paypal redirects back to my page, he appends to url transaction
>   token and payer ID but I don't have any information about quantity of
>   products which user bought.

You can append the pre conversation id to the url you pass to Paypal as the return url. This way the conversation id will be passed back together with the above parameters and `seam` will know to restore the prepayment conversation with all the data.